# How to use font in code format?

Tags: fonts

What's the command for displaying `<receive>`, `<reply>` and so on as appearing in the following picture?

[image]

Comment: `\texttt{<receive>}`

Comment: perhaps `\verb|...|` is better if say `_` occurs in the text

Comment: Why close votes as "too localized"? This question sure is extremely basic of nature and should be covered in about every introduction to LaTeX, but it's not too localized -- it rather is extremely widely applicable.

Comment: @doncherry: I'm not for closing, but downvoting: The question shows no research effort: Reading _any_ introduction to LaTeX would answer it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "typewriter type" font is obtained by

```
\texttt{<receive>}
```

In case your input contains special characters, such as `%` or `_`, you can use

```
\verb|abc%def_ghi|
```

where the two bars can be *any* other non special character that doesn't appear in the string.

Every good introduction to LaTeX covers the topic.